# NPE, интент нулл

Tags: android, android-intent

Просто перехожу через `onActivityResult()` в другую активити, пытаюсь вернуть данные, на что вылетает NPE, хотя все места, где он может появиться я вроде перекрыл, интент создавал самыми разными способами:

MainActivity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentList fragment = FragmentList.newInstance("header", "body", Importance.noMatter);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_list_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        initToolbar();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                @Importance
                int importance = getIntent().getIntExtra("Importance", Importance.noMatter);

                String header = data.getExtras().getString("header").toString();//ошибка здесь
                String body = data.getExtras().getString("body").toString();

                FragmentList fragment = FragmentList.newInstance(header, body, importance);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list_container, fragment);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Нежелательное поведение случилось",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
```

Активити (NewNote), где инициализируются поля и возвращаются на главную:

```
 private void initiateSpinner() {
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.importance_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


  @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_note);
        initToolbar();
        initViews();
        initiateSpinner();


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                @Importance
                int temp = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                intent = new Intent();
                switch (temp) {

                    case 0:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", temp);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Log.v("итем", "item = 1");
                        intent.putExtra("importance", temp);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", temp);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", temp);
                        break;
                    default:
                        intent.putExtra("importance", 0);
                        Log.v("итем", "дефолт = " + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        break;
                }
            }


        header.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (header.getText().length() == 32) {
                    header.setError("Слишком длинный заголовок");
                }
            }



        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (header.getText().length() == 0) {
                    header.setError("Необходимо заполнить");
                    return;
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("header", header.getText());
                    Log.v("new","header" + header.getText());

                }

                intent.putExtra("body", body.getText());
                Log.v("new","body" + body.getText());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                finish();

            }
        });

    }
```

Не знаю, поможет ли - но еще белым текстом в консоли выдает ошибку:

```
setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled = false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false, mIsTouchExplorationEnabled = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked
     at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.setStateLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:553)
     at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.tryConnectToServiceLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:636)
     at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.<init>(AccessibilityManager.java:226)
     at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.getInstance(AccessibilityManager.java:206)
     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9941)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.initViewGroup(ViewGroup.java:536)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:525)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:520)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:516)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:512)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:119)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.<init>(PhoneWindow.java:2346)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3643)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4036)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:367)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:316)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:281)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at com.asgard.smartnotes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

UPD:

`Header` и `Body` доходят:

```
10-24 19:24:02.019 32027-32027/com.asgard.smartnotes V/new: header п
10-24 19:24:02.019 32027-32027/com.asgard.smartnotes V/new: body р
10-24 19:24:02.025 32027-32027/com.asgard.smartnotes D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{1a149ed5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@10eab6ea {com.asgard.smartnotes/com.asgard.smartnotes.NewNote}}
```

Comment: А вот это `intent.putExtra("header", header.getText());` точно выполняется?

Comment: @post_zeew логи дойти не успевают, тост тоже не показывается, вылетает сразу. Не знаю, почему

Comment: @post_zeew вру, доходит, не заметил из за той ошибки с локом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело было в том, что я не удалил `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`